# Backend generated nested JSON formArray and fromGroup in angular 2

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-forms, formarray

I want to generate JSON driven form with array of object, currently [stackbiz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamicforms-blogarticle-fjkjx4?file=app%2Fdynamic-form.component.ts) is working on single object json (person.js), I am trying to modify person.ts with below array of JSON

for json

```
[{
  name: {
    label: 'Name',
    value: 'Juri',
    type: 'text',
    validation: {
      required: true
    }
  },
  age: {
    label: 'Age',
    value: 32,
    type: 'text'
  },
  gender: {
    label: 'Gender',
    value: 'M',
    type: 'radio',
    options: [
      { label: "Male", value: 'M'},
      { label: "Female", value: 'F'}
    ]
  }, 
  city: {
    label: 'City',
    value: '39010',
    type: 'select',
    options: [
      { label: "(choose one)", value: ''},
      { label: "Bolzano", value: '39100'},
      { label: "Meltina", value: '39010'},
      { label: "Appiano", value: '39057'}
    ],
    validation: {
      required: true
    }
  }
},
{
  name: {
    label: 'Name',
    value: 'Juri1',
    type: 'text',
    validation: {
      required: true
    }
  },
  age: {
    label: 'Age',
    value: 32,
    type: 'text'
  },
  gender: {
    label: 'Gender',
    value: 'M',
    type: 'radio',
    options: [
      { label: "Male", value: 'M'},
      { label: "Female", value: 'F'}
    ]
  }
}]
```

So template output should be something like this (including both section)

## [image]

[image]

The issue which Im facing in above multi object json is that I looping through array of object and creating formGroup with new formControl in loop, and then try to push into formArray outside of loop but not success, any help or suggestion appreciated, I stuck in formArray vs FormBuilder vs FormGroup and now brain is not working :(

here is plunker link I am trying to modify : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamicforms-blogarticle-fjkjx4

Answer (score 0):

You can just create an empty formArray to store the responses. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamicforms-blogarticle-jns9xq

```js
public formResponses: FormArray = new FormArray([]);
```

```js
  onSubmit(form) {
    if (form.valid) {
      this.formResponses.push(new FormControl(form.value));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, My mistake in explanation, I want to generate template(UI) based on JSON supplied in person.ts, currently it has single object So it's generating a single section, but I what happen if array of object as mentioned above,  section should be repeat